# How to set timestampsInSnapshots setting with firebase-admin for NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Because of the warning about the upcoming change in timestamp behavior in Firestore, I am trying to change the initialisation code for my app.

> The behavior for Date objects stored in Firestore is going to change
>   AND YOUR APP MAY BREAK. To hide this warning and ensure your app does
>   not break, you need to add the following code to your app before
>   calling any other Cloud Firestore methods:
>
> const firestore = firebase.firestore(); const settings = {/ your
>   settings... / timestampsInSnapshots: true};
>   firestore.settings(settings);
>
> With this change, timestamps stored in Cloud Firestore will be read
>   back as Firebase Timestamp objects instead of as system Date objects.

I can't find any reference to firestore "settings" though. Would something like this work? The Typescript definition says no...

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

export const adminApp = admin.initializeApp();

const firestore = admin.firestore(adminApp);
firestore.settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true });
```

Comment: "Timestamp doesn’t exist yet in the admin SDK.  They’re working on it." ~ @codingdoug (on Firebase Slack)

Comment: Then why does the warning show up?

Comment: The warning showed up because I was also using the client library in my backend code. And in general I think if you see this warning in a front-end/client application you would expect this to be relevant for the backend as well.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I've upgraded the firebase-admin to 5.13.0 and with the following node.js code in my index.js after initializeApp(), that warning went away and my code runs correctly afterwards.

```
admin.initializeApp();
const settings = {/* your settings... */ timestampsInSnapshots: true};
admin.firestore().settings(settings);
```

Comment: Thanks. I can confirm that with the updated version this works now. Typescript also allows the API from its typedef.

Comment: How do you upgrade the firebase-admin?

Comment: @JeffPadgett `npm install --save firebase-admin@latest`

Comment: If you are using the result of `initializeApp` (e.g. `const app = admin.initializeApp(/* ... */);`), you can write the settings using its result (e.g. `app.firestore().settings(setting)`).  

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.app.App

Comment: Applying settings makes the resulting `db` into a void instead of a `Firestore` type. Is this the expected behaviour?